# How to check/select if a string contains value from a table column values?

Tags: sql, oracle

Lets say I have this number 123456789 and I have a table column which have different values numbers like:

```
TABLE_COLUMN
123
456
555
763
```

Is there a way to do something like SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE 123456789 CONTAINS (values from that table column).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you looking for this?

```
select t.*
from table t
where cast(123456789 as varchar2(255)) like '%' || cast(table_column as varchar2(255)) || '%';
```

The explicit casts are not necessary, but I'm not a fan of implicit type conversion.

Comment: Thanks for answering. Im looking for something like this, I don't know how to explain it:

`foreach num in numbers check if 1234567.contains(num)`

if it containts that num, then select it.

Comment: @Popplar . . . I think that is what this does, depending on what you mean by "contains".

Comment: @GordonLinoff - No, not quite. The OP wants to test if the input string contains any of the strings in that column. Your query does something else - it returns ALL the substrings in the column that the input contains as a substring.

Comment: Actually, you are absolutely right. I was using an incorrect input and thats why the select wasn't returning any row. Luckily I don't need to cast since both of them will have the same type (number).

Comment: @mathguy Yeah, thats what I want to do. Gordon answer does it I think?, return the rows in which the value of a column from that row is contained in the input string.

Answer (score 1):

How about `INSTR`?

```
SQL> with test (tc) as
  2    (select '123' from dual union all
  3     select '456' from dual union all
  4     select '555' from dual union all
  5     select '763' from dual
  6    )
  7  select *
  8  from test
  9  where instr('123456789', tc) > 0;

TC
---
123
456

SQL>
```

Answer (score 1):

You show some pseudo-code, but I doubt that's what you want to do. You show "select * from table where..." - is the string 123456789 in the same table where you have the column against which you must check? That sounds odd.

Rather, I imagine you have a table with a column of values against which you must test, and an "input" value (either a single one or perhaps values in ANOTHER table), and you must test that input value against ALL the values (in ALL rows) in the "test" table.

If so, you probably want something like this... I show the input as a bind variable, but you can change this easily for other uses.

```
select <whatever>
from   <wherever>
where  exists (select * from <table> where instr(:input_string, table_column) > 0)
```

If the inputs (or the values stored in that column) are numbers instead of strings, you can convert to strings using `TO_CHAR()`.